# Blank index.php vs. Options -Indexes to disallow directory listings?

Tags: php, apache, security, .htaccess, directory-listing

It seems like it would be a good idea to completely stop people from being able to view directory listings (to improve security and protect content) and from the reading I've done I've found two ways to do it:

Way #1: Put a blank index.php/index.html file in each directory
Way #2: Put the line `Options -Indexes` in a .htaccess file in each directory

Which one of those is preferable? Or, is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, a question that really needs to be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Options -Indexes` (at root, not directory level) when you don't want *any* directory listings exposed.

Use the blank index.html when some directories are ok to list, but some are to be kept private

Comment: You can also turn off directory listing in apache.conf (or httpd.conf depending on distro) using the Options -Indexes command